# Is there a way to delete unused files from PyTorch to run a light version of it?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, neural-network, pytorch

Hi I am trying to upload a zip archive of required libraries to run my project on AWS Lambda. Since the size of the zipped PyTorch library exceeds the size limit of AWS Lambda, I am looking to decrease the number of files I upload from the library.

I have a trained neural network and I need PyTorch just to carry out the inference on Lambda.

Is there a list of files that I can delete from the package? Is there a way to identify these files?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

a walk around would be using Lambda support for EFS. You could prestage your dependencies to a folder structure in EFS and then point the lambda to run there. You should then be able to import the pytorch and any other packages you place as subdirectories under the working directory.

Comment: This works but I wanted to know if there was an easier alternative by just deleting files from the library since it is unreasonably heavy.